# When would it be true that $k$ a natural number divides $n!$ but not $(n-1)!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

When would it be true that $k$ a natural number divides $n!$ but not $(n-1)!$? I asked this question myself when trying to solve the second problem of INMO 2010. For this to happen, I think that $n$ should have some prime component of $k$ so that when $(n-1)!$ comes, it won't have those prime components [as the gcd of $(n,n-1)=1$] and hence it won't divide $(n-1)!$. Am I right with this argument? Also does this work for $k=n$ as well?

Comment: What you're saying isn't very precise (what is a "prime component"?), but it makes sense roughly. Have you thought about how exactly divisibility relates to prime factorizations?

Comment: Don't forget that $n!=n \cdot (n-1)!$

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A002034

Comment: I doubt that there is an easy criterion when $k$ satisfies $k\mid n!$ and $k\nmid (n-1)!$

Comment: Are you familiar with the multiplicity $m_p(n)$ of prime $p$ as a factor of $n!$? It is
$$m_p(n)=\sum_{j\ge1}\lfloor\frac n{p^j}\rfloor.$$ You are looking for numbers $k$ such that for at least one prime $p$ the multiplicity of $p$ as a factor of $k$ exceeds $m_p(n-1)$ but for all the primes $p$ its multiplicity is at most $m_p(n)$. For there to be a difference between $m_p(n-1)$ and $m_p(n)$ you need $n$ to be divisible by $p$, but as we see, there's more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k \mid n!$ but not $k \mid (n-1)!$, then the following is true:

1. $k$ has a factor of the form $p^x$, that divides $n!$.  For example, 125 divides 15! but not 14".
2. There may be a co-factor in $k$ that does divide $(n-1)!$.  So 8 divides 14! and there for 1000 divides 15! but not 14!
3. Several primes may be involved in step (1), for example, $3^6 5^3$ divides 15! but neither $3^6$ or $5^3$ divide 14!